# Mongoid Criteria unexpected results when searching a document by id

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, mongoid, mongoid4

I have a Mongoid Criteria of `users` and I want to find a user. Given a `user` that I'm sure doesn't exists in the criteria:

```
>> users.where(email: user.email).exists?
=> false

>> users.map(&:id).include?(user.id)
=> false
```

When I search by `id` I always get the user instead of nil:

```
>> users.find(user.id)
=> #<User _id: 521a43b37

>> users.where(id: user.id).first
=> #<User _id: 521a43b37

>> users.where(_id: user.id).first
=> #<User _id: 521a43b37

>> users.where(id: user.id).exists?
=> true
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks in advance.

PS: mongoid (4.0.0.beta1), rails (4.0.1), ruby (2.1.0), mongoDB (2.4.9)

Comment: What does `users.map(&:id)` return?

Comment: An array of user_ids: `[BSON::ObjectId('5314fd245669630667bc0000'), ...]`.

Comment: So what `users.map(&:id).first` outputs for example?

Comment: `>> users.map(&:id).first
=> BSON::ObjectId('4fbdb527e8c355d83ba6e4f0')`

Comment: And what `users.map(&:_id).first` gives?

Comment: Exactly the same. I have tried the queries with `user.id`, `user._id`, `user`. Also `where(_id: ...)`.

Comment: Is there any possibility that the `user` you are having trouble with is an incomplete record (that has no `email`) ?

Comment: No, it has email and it's a valid user. Besides there are not users with email `nil`.